# Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean in while loop

Tags: java, boolean

I just started learning java, tried to find the answer but I guess I'm not smart enough. 
I'm trying to write an array which I got from some file into another file.

The problem is when I'm trying to make "while" it's saying cannot convert from int to boolean. Can anyone suggest something. Thank you in advance.
 This is what I have :

```
public void savethefile() throws IOException{

File file1= new File("lala.ppm");
FileWriter save=new FileWriter(file1);
save.write(tytul);

while(i){
    save.write(arraycomment[i]);
    i++;
}

save.close();
```

Comment: BTW: What is `tytul` and `arraycomment` ?

Comment: Use a boolean instead of an int inside your `while`. The error really does say it all. It can be confusing if you're coming from `C`, but in java there are booleans, and they're not integers.

Answer (score 6):

Presumably `i` is an `int`, not a `boolean`.  Unlike C/C++, this won't be converted to a `boolean` implicitly.  You must explicitly state your condition as a `boolean`.

```
while (i < arraycomment.length) // or some other constant
```

Comment: yes, I'm starting to see these differents in C++ and Java. Thank you so much!

Comment: Starting with 15 minutes after you post the question, you can "accept" an answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer that you feel is the most helpful.